# Working with WebCenter Content UCM workflow

Tags: oracle, workflow, content-management, webcenter

Which of the Java-libraries can give me access to the management of workflows (creating, adding files to workflow).

How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the workflows using the exposed services.
Please refer to the Oracle documentation.

I've put links in for both the 10g and 11g services since they remained much the same between the releases.

[Oracle 11g Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e11011/c06_workflow.htm#i1052440)

[Oracle 10g Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10316_01/cs/cs_doc_10/documentation/developer/services_reference_10gr3en.pdf)